# could not find function proportions

Tags: gtsummary

> `library(gtsummary)`

```
Medicinreview <- rep(c("Yes","No"), c(20,17))
> sex <- rep(c("Male","Female"), c(12,25))
> age <- round(runif(n=37, min=37, max=94), 0)
> 
> head(data.frame(Medicinreview,sex,age))
```

Medicinreview  sex age
1           Yes Male  71
2           Yes Male  40
3           Yes Male  46
4           Yes Male  62
5           Yes Male  64
6           Yes Male  50

> 

```
data.frame(Medicinreview,sex,age) %>%               
+               tbl_summary(by = Medicinreview)
```

> 

```
data.frame(Medicinreview,sex,age) %>%               
+               tbl_summary(by = Medicinreview) %>% add_p
```

Error in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `test = map2(...)`.
Caused by error in `map2()`:
i In index: 1.
Caused by error in `proportions()`:
! could not find function "proportions"
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

> 

```
data.frame(Medicinreview,sex,age) %>% 
+   tbl_summary(by = Medicinreview, 
+               missing = "no", 
+               label = list(Medicinreview ~ "Medicinreview")) %>% add_p
```

Error in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `test = map2(...)`.
Caused by error in `map2()`:
i In index: 1.
Caused by error in `proportions()`:
! could not find function "proportions"
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

> `rlang::last_trace()`

### <error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `test = map2(...)`.
Caused by error in `map2()`:
i In index: 1.
Caused by error in `proportions()`:
! could not find function "proportions"

Backtrace:
x

1. +-... %>% add_p
2. +-gtsummary::add_p(.)
3. +-gtsummary:::add_p.tbl_summary(.)
4. | -... %>% ...
5. +-dplyr::mutate(...)
6. +-dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
7. | -dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
8. |   +-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
9. |   -dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
10. |     -mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
11. |       -dplyr (local) eval()
12. +-purrr::map2(...)
13. | -purrr:::map2_("list", .x, .y, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
14. |   +-purrr:::with_indexed_errors(...)
15. |   | -base::withCallingHandlers(...)
16. |   +-purrr:::call_with_cleanup(...)
17. |   -gtsummary (local) .f(.x[[i]], .y[[i]], ...)
18. |     -gtsummary:::.assign_test_tbl_summary(...)
19. |       +-base::suppressWarnings(...)
20. |       | -base::withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = function(w) invokeRestart("muffleWarning"))
21. |       -... %>% min()
22. +-dplyr::pull(., exp)
23. -dplyr::mutate(...)

> `sessionInfo()`
> R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows Server x64 (build 14393)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] gtsummary_1.7.2.9000

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] pillar_1.9.0         compiler_3.6.1       forcats_1.0.0        tools_3.6.1          digest_0.6.27
[6] lifecycle_1.0.3      tibble_3.2.1         gtable_0.3.0         pkgconfig_2.0.3      rlang_1.1.1
[11] DBI_1.1.1            cli_3.6.1            rstudioapi_0.13      commonmark_1.9.0     xfun_0.39
[16] fastmap_1.1.0        withr_2.4.3          dplyr_1.1.2          stringr_1.4.0        xml2_1.3.3
[21] knitr_1.43           rappdirs_0.3.3       generics_0.1.3       vctrs_0.6.3          sass_0.4.6
[26] grid_3.6.1           tidyselect_1.2.0     glue_1.6.2           R6_2.5.1             fansi_0.5.0
[31] purrr_1.0.1          tidyr_1.1.4          magrittr_2.0.3       scales_1.2.1         htmltools_0.5.5
[36] ellipsis_0.3.2       broom.helpers_1.13.0 gt_0.9.0             colorspace_2.0-2     utf8_1.1.4
[41] stringi_1.7.6        munsell_0.5.0        markdown_1.7

Comment: I have tried both with the latest version and the development version of gtsummary

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't update to a newer R version due to firm policies

Comment: Please update your post with a minimal reprex, aka a reproducible example including code and data we can run on our machines

Comment: `library(gtsummary)

Medicinreview <- rep(c("Yes","No"), c(20,17))
sex <- rep(c("Male","Female"), c(12,25))
age <- round(runif(n=37, min=37, max=94), 0)

head(data.frame(Medicinreview,sex,age))

data.frame(Medicinreview,sex,age) %>%               
              tbl_summary(by = Medicinreview)

data.frame(Medicinreview,sex,age) %>%               
              tbl_summary(by = Medicinreview) %>% add_p

data.frame(Medicinreview,sex,age) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = Medicinreview, 
              missing = "no", 
              label = list(Medicinreview ~ "Medicinreview")) %>% add_p`